# Un tech savvy user needs help

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite

My mother is 100 and has macular degeneration. Her eye doctor recommended the Kindle Paperwhite. She has never used a computer and I bought a Paperwhite and set it up for her. The backlighting and large font works great for her but I need a way to limit the screens she sees to just the pages of the book she is reading. Is there any way to have it open to the book only? She can’t see the options because they are tiny and she wouldn’t know what choices to make anyway. We can change the book for her as needed and download books using our WiFi. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you press the on/off button when you finished a chapter to put the Kindle in sleep mode, all you have to do is press it again to show the last page.
If your mother's Paperwhite is the latest Paperwhite model, you could also attach a [Kindle Audio Adapter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVLpyTvPdyc).

Comment: Welcome to SE-ebooks. You may have found the answer to your question elsewhere, but it would be standard courtesy to answer here people who try to help you. Furthermore, you can also answer your own question for the benefit of others.